# Combining old, with new settings

Tags: javascript, object, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I know the code set up like this works, 
I just don't know if it is one that is good to use, and won't be problematic, meaning there won't be issues with it.

Is it doing what we want it to be doing, yes.
It combines the **oldSettings**, with the **newSettings**.
Can it be written better than how it is written here, I don't know.
**It might be able to be improved.**

**Code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnj7quby/8/

```
function combineSettings(oldSettings, newSettings) {
    const playerVars = Object.assign({}, oldSettings.playerVars, newSettings.playerVars);
    const settings = Object.assign({}, oldSettings, newSettings);
    settings.playerVars = playerVars;
    return settings;
}
```

**oldSettings**

Which are the: defaultSettings

```
const defaultSettings = {
    playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
        controls: 1,
        showinfo: 1,
        rel: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        cc_load_policy: 0,
        fs: 0,
        disablekb: 1
    },
```

**newSettings**
Are any settings that get added to it.

```
loadPlayer({
    target: ".jacketc",
    width: 600,
    height: 338,
    start: 200,
    end: 205,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".playa",
    start: 8,
    end: 12,
    loop: true
});
```

Comment: Seems you want codereview - if it works it works

Comment: Can it be improved from how it is written there?

Comment: Maybe add an example of your two settings to your question.

Comment: Done!...I just did that.

Comment: @mplungjan What if I removed function combineSettings, and set it up this way instead? https://jsfiddle.net/g6oaht8f/115/ Is this a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const defaultSettings = {
  playerVars: {
    autoplay: 1,
    controls: 1,
    showinfo: 1,
    rel: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3,
    cc_load_policy: 0,
    fs: 0,
    disablekb: 1
  }
}

const newSettings = {
  target: ".jacketc",
  width: 600,
  height: 338,
  start: 200,
  end: 205,
  loop: true
}

const mergedSettings = {
  ...defaultSettings,
  playerVars: {
    ...defaultSettings.playerVars,
    ...newSettings
  }
};

console.log(mergedSettings);
```

Comment: Can you provide an updated jsfiddle with your recommendation please? https://jsfiddle.net/Lnj7quby/8/

Comment: I'm not going to update that fiddle as I can't get it to work. Just test the code to see if it works yourself.

Comment: Thank you for providing a recommendation. Someone may be able to look at it and see if it will work or not, or may be able to make adjustments to it.

Comment: If it currently works and you know what your code means there's no reason to change it.

Comment: What if I removed function combineSettings, and set it up this way instead? https://jsfiddle.net/g6oaht8f/114/ Is this a better way to do it?